# How to install a color theme for Emacs 24?

Tags: package, themes, emacs24.4

Recently, I found [a website](http://emacsthemes.caisah.info/) providing many color themes for Emacs, so I decided to install one. However, I was confused by some instructions from web or other forums and I couldn't manage to install anything.

So I come here to ask for help, hope someone could help me install a color theme for Emacs!

My OS is Ubuntu.

PS: I have downloaded one color theme, extract it to a folder called elisp, and wrote the following command in the `.emacs` file

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "~/elisp/black-theme-master")
(require 'blackboard-theme)
```

when I open Emacs,  it gives me an error warning.

```
Warning (initialization): An error occurred while loading `/home/shieh/.emacs':

File error: Cannot open load file, blackboard-theme

To ensure normal operation, you should investigate and remove the
cause of the error in your initialization file.  Start Emacs with
the `--debug-init' option to view a complete error backtrace
```

the theme I got is here: [Blackborad theme](http://emacsthemes.caisah.info/blackboard-theme/)

Comment: Could you edit your answer to explain what you have tried so far, please?

Comment: Please also provide the link to where you got the color theme.  A google search turned up [this version of `blackboard-theme`](https://github.com/don9z/blackboard-theme), which suggests you need to use `(load-theme 'blackboard t)` in your init file.

Comment: You mistyped "blackboard" as "blackborad". I suspect that there are other typos. Once you have found and fixed them, things will likely work as expected. As far as I know "Cannot open load file, SOMEFILE" always means "SOMEFILE isn't on the load-path". You say you did put it on the load-path, but that likely isn't true, probably because of a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's more efficient to have a directory i.e., ~/.emacs.d/site-lisp or ~/elisp, act as a default directory for your byte-compiled/source files, and have emacs add that directory (and its **sub-directories**) to its load path as such:

```
(let ((default-directory (expand-file-name "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/")))
  (setq load-path
        (append
         (let ((load-path (copy-sequence load-path)))
           (append 
            (copy-sequence (normal-top-level-add-to-load-path '(".")))
            (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path)))
         load-path)))
```

Then adding your theme is as simple as

```
git clone https://github.com/don9z/blackboard-theme.git ~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/blackboard-theme
```

And in your ~/.emacs.d/init.el

```
(require 'blackboard-theme)
```

--

I would recommend using melpa, where applicable, however.

Comment: Or just `(let ((default-directory "~/.emacs.d/site-lisp/")) (normal-top-level-add-subdirs-to-load-path))`, as it does it's job by side-effect. Also `(append (copy-sequence a-list) ... last-list)` doesn't make sense, because `append` already copies all lists but the last. To add the top-level just add `add-to-list`.

Comment: This solution looks far too complicated to me.  It is also too generic.  It doesn't really address "how to install a color theme" but rather "how to alter `load-path` to make `require` more convenient".

Answer (score 3):

If you have the theme file stored at `~/elisp/black-theme-maste/blackboard-theme.el` use the following:

```
(add-to-list 'custom-theme-load-path "~/elisp/black-theme-maste/")
(load-theme 'blackboard)
```

Edit: 
You have to omit the "-theme" in `load-theme` part; however, it is required in the filename for emacs to recognize it as a theme.

Comment: I still get the same error. Can you provide me another way to install a Emacs color theme(Need specific instructions!)

Comment: The OP stated in the question that he/she extracted the file to the `elisp` directory -- perhaps that's the problem with trying to use a sub-directory called `black-theme-maste` (especially when that sub-directory may not exist)?

Comment: @chinashieh Check for typos. Are your really adding an existing directory which does contain the theme to the load-path? E.g. why "maste" did you mean "master"?

Comment: Entries of `load-path` and similar should not and with a slash. It doesn't really hurt if they do, but you might get duplicated, but non-`equal` entries.